# Grouping sequences with linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My task is:
A sequence of non-empty strings stringList is given, containing only uppercase letters of the
Latin alphabet.
For all strings starting with the same letter, determine their total length and obtain a sequence
of strings of the form "S-C", where S is the total length of all strings from stringList that begin
with the character C. Order the resulting sequence in descending order of the numerical values
of the sums, and for equal values of the sums, in ascending order of the C character codes.
Everything needs to be done in one line via linq.

I tried this:

```cs
return stringList.GroupBy(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
    .Select(x => x.ToString().Length + "-" + x.Key)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Length)
    .ThenBy(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

But this one does not work properly.

Comment: Please turn this into a [mre].

Comment: C# is a language of types. In your first `Select` what is the type of `x`? What is the meaning of `x.ToString()` for that type? Is that related to what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The following method will take a list of strings and returns the results as you have asked for:

```
IEnumerable<string> ProcessValues(IEnumerable<string> strings) {
    return strings.GroupBy(s => s.FirstOrDefault())
                  .Select(group => (Character: group.Key, Length: group.Sum(s => s.Length)))
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Length)
                  .ThenBy(g => g.Character)
                  .Select(g => $"{g.Length}-{g.Character}");
}
```

An example of the results you can expect is provided below:

```
var stringList = new List<string> { "Hello", "How", "Are", "You", "Today" }
var result = ProcessValues(stringList); // { "8-H", "5-T", "3-A", "3-Y" }
```

Comment: Given the problem (homework) constraints, I would use `s[0]` over `s.FirstOrDefault()` - we know `s` is non-empty, and no reason to add extra method calls. I would also change the parameter names after the first `Select` to be `cl` or maybe `char_len` to indicate the new data being processed.